# How to get the breadcrumb from a module template?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I'm using D8 and I want to display only the first item of the breadcrumb in a block. So I need the breadcrumb, and manipulate it to display only the first item. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Have you tried the [EasyBreadcrumb module](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb)? It has an option to display only the first item, haven't tried it with module breadcrumbs though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already use EasyBreadcrumd. But I haven't seen this option. And the first item is "Home"... D8 by the way.

Comment: I meant to use the option `Paths to be excluded while generating segments`

Comment: Ok ! But that will affect the breadcrumb displayed somewhere else as real breadcrumb !?